# How can I use SQL::Abstract's special operators inside DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbix-class

I am trying to find a way to use [`SQL::Abstract`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL%3a%3aAbstract)'s [`special operators`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL%3a%3aAbstract#SPECIAL-OPERATORS) inside [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass).

My goal is to be able to use sqlite's MATCH operator for full text search so that I can do

```
$d->search({ textcontent => { -match => "sqlite" }})
```

to produce a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE textcontent MATCH 'sqlite';
```

I think I can figure out how to do that with `SQL::Abstract`, but I cannot find how to fiddle with the sql generator inside `DBIx::Class`. I guess that would be inside [`DBIx::Class::SQLMaker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSQLMaker), though I don't know how I would access that save for subclassing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be undocumented, but one of the ["extra attributes"](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aStorage%3a%3aDBI#DBIx%3a%3aClass-specific-connection-attributes) that you can put on a DBIC `connect_info` (i.e. the arguments to `connect`) is `sql_maker_options`. So you can try this out by calling e.g.

```
$schema->connect($dsn, $username, $password, undef,
    {
        sql_maker_options => {
            special_ops => {
                 ...
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The SQLMaker is a subclass of `SQL::Abstract` and should accept the same options unless something says otherwise (and it doesn't).